# how to get the required result, the result is array list?

Tags: java

I have an array of object, which is basically an Arraylist.
The input and output data look like this

```
 data=  [
      {
        id:1,
        parent:0
      },
       {
        id:2,
        parent:0
      },

       {
        id:3,
        parent:1
      },
       {
        id:4,
        parent:1
      },
       {
        id:5,
        parent:3
      },
       {
        id:6,
        parent:3
      }
    ]
```

if parent of any object is equal to id, then that will become the children the result should look like this.

```
    [
      {
        id:1,
        parent:0,
        children:[
                  {
                    id:3,
                    parent:1,
                    children:[ {
                                id:5,
                                parent:3
                               },
                               {
                                id:6,
                                parent:3
                                }
                              ]
                    },
                   {
                    id:4,
                    parent:1
                  }
          ]
      },
       {
        id:2,
        parent:0
      }

    ]
```

Because i am not able to access the inner element of the array of object by using for loop, i am not able to put condition on it.
i try using something like this

```
for(Map <String,Object> individual_object: data) {

}
```

How to do this?

My complete code:

```
try {
            taxonDao.openCurrentSession();
            List<Object[]> taxonList = taxonDao.list(parent, classificationId, taxonIds, expand_taxon);
            List res = new ArrayList();

            Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            TaxonUI ui = new TaxonUI();
            Map<Long, Map<String, Object>> m2 = new HashMap<Long, Map<String, Object>>();
            for (Object[] t : taxonList) {
                Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                ui.setId((Long) t[0]);
                ui.setTaxonid((Long) t[0]);
                ui.setClassification((Long) t[4]);
                ui.setPath((String) t[3]);
                ui.setText((String) t[1]);
                ui.setRank((Integer) t[2]);
                if(t[5]!=null){
                    ui.setParent((Long)t[5]);
                }
                m.put("id", ui.getId());
                m.put("taxonid", ui.getId());
                m.put("text", ui.getText());
                m.put("rank", ui.getRank());
                m.put("path", ui.getPath());
                m.put("classification", ui.getClassification());
                m.put("parent", ui.getParent());
                res.add(m);
            }

            return res;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            taxonDao.closeCurrentSession();
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of the object within your arraylist?

Comment: a Map type object:::Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need an Item class to store the id and parent id:

(The toString() is for debugging so you can print the input and output list to verify the result)

```
public class Item {
    private final int parentId;
    private final int id;

    private final java.util.List<Item> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Item(int parentId, int id) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addChild(Item child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "id: " + id + ", parent: " + parentId;

        if (children.isEmpty() == false) {
            result += ", children: " + children;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
}
```

Then as usual, a Main class and main method to prepare the input and process it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.List<Item> inputItems = createInputItems();
        java.util.List<Item> oututItems = processItemsToParentChildren(inputItems);

        System.out.println(oututItems);     
    }
```

The create input method is straight forward:

```
private static List<Item> createInputItems() {
    java.util.List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();


    result.add(new Item(0, 1));
    result.add(new Item(0, 2));

    result.add(new Item(1, 3));
    result.add(new Item(1, 4));

    result.add(new Item(3, 5));
    result.add(new Item(3, 6));

    return result;
}
```

Then you need a method to map id to the corresponding item:

```
private static Map<Integer, Item> prepareIdItemMap(List<Item> items) {
    HashMap<Integer, Item> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Item eachItem : items) {
        result.put(Integer.valueOf(eachItem.getId()), eachItem);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then the critical part, to add the correct child items to their parent, or to root of the list if parent id is 0:

```
private static List<Item> processItemsToParentChildren(List<Item> items) {
    java.util.List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Integer, Item> idItemMap = prepareIdItemMap(items);

    for (Item eachItem : items) {
        int parentId = eachItem.getParentId();

        if (parentId == 0) {
            result.add(eachItem);
        } else {
            idItemMap.get(Integer.valueOf(parentId)).addChild(eachItem);
        }
    }


        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Good approach.
More or less all the answers on this question are same, but your are more details one.Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Hi a small query, if children list is empty it still showing the empty list, how to remove that :)

Comment: You mean in the printout? Do you skip the children list if checked isEmpty() like in my toString() method?

Comment: As i am using JAckson serialize, that will work::::::@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)

Answer (score 1):

Why not define a `Class` with the following fields (Let's define this class name as `ParentChildClass`:

```
public class ParentChildClass{
    int id;
    ParentChildClass parent;
    ArrayList<ParentChildClass> children;
    ParentChildClass(ParentChildClass parent){
        this.children = new ArrayList<ParentChildClass>();
        if(parent != null){
            this.parent  = parent;
        }
    }
    //getter and setters

    //method to add a child
    public void addChild(ParentChildClass child){
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

Now wrap this inside a `HashMap<Integer, ParentChildClass>` to easily access all the elements by their ids. Iterate through the `object` you currently have and start adding these elements one by one in the `HashMap` by creating instances of `ParentChildClass`. If the parent is already not present in the `HashMap`, find the element with parent's id, include it in the `HashMap` by creating its new instance (Don't add the parent recursively now, as you'll anyway come later to this element while iterating, when you can add the parent for this object as well). After doing this, set this newly created parent element as the parent of the Child element, and proceed.

In the end, you'll be left with a map that has references to all the parent child objects which can be used to access and element in O(1), its parent and all its children (in the arraylist).

Comment: I appreciate your help, still i need to figure out how to do it. But i think that will work.

Comment: @user2903536 Glad I could help. Is there anything which is still unclear, in which I could help?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect elements to their parents by first looping them through and collecting their IDs to a map. This will allow you to then find a parent for each element after you loop them through again to construct the hierarchy that you described. Note that you also need to collect to elements without parents (called roots below.

```
List<MyElement> list = asList(
        new MyElement(1, 0),
        new MyElement(2, 0),
        new MyElement(3, 1),
        new MyElement(4, 1),
        new MyElement(5, 3),
        new MyElement(6, 3));

Map<Integer, MyElement> elementsById = new HashMap<>();
for (MyElement element : list) {
    elementsById.put(element.getId(), element);
}

List<MyElement> roots = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyElement element : elementsById.values()) {
    if (elementsById.containsKey(element.getParent())) {
        MyElement parent = elementsById.get(element.getParent());
        parent.addChild(element);
    } else {
        roots.add(element);
    }
}

System.out.println(roots);
```

MyElement class for reference

```
public class MyElement {
    private int id;
    private int parent;
    private List<MyElement> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyElement(int id, int parent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{id=" + id + ", children=" + children + "}";
    }

    public void addChild(MyElement child) {
        if (child.parent != id) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected parent id " + id + " got " + child.parent);
        }
        children.add(child);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public List<MyElement> getChildren() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, still i need to figure out how to do it. But i think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner fields of your object is `private`, you cannot access them by name.
you cannot write `object.field`

You need to have accessors to get their value

your code will be `object.getFiled()`